# How do all classes inherit from Object?

Tags: java, class, object, inheritance

All classes inherit from `java.lang.Object`, although `extends Object` is (generally) not written out anywhere. How is this possible?

Answer (score 26):

if you don't explicitly write `extends Object` the compiler does it for you. So knowing that a class can only extend one super class, the compiler will look at the hierarchy and extend the highest super class to `Object`. So every class will directly or indirectly inherit the `Object` class.

The `Object` class however is a special case because it doesn't extend anything.

Lastly if you were to compile a simple class and decompile it, you will see the compiler inserts extends 
`java.lang.Object` (or 
the bytecode equivalent) 
into the class

Comment: I wonder if you can get around this in the bytecode and make other classes that don't extend anything?  That might add efficiency to the program if so.

Answer (score 6):

The `Object` is implicitly direct/indirect super class of all class.

From [Oracle Java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html):

> **Definitions:** A class that is derived from another class is called a
> subclass (also a derived class, extended class, or child class). The
> class from which the subclass is derived is called a superclass (also
> a base class or a parent class).
>
> Excepting `Object`, which has no superclass, every class has one and
> only one direct superclass (single inheritance). ***In the absence of any
> other explicit superclass, every class is implicitly a subclass of
> `Object`.***