# what does Object do in java?

Tags: java

I have this code in java and I do not understand the meaning of the Object in the following code ...

Here is the code

```
public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo foo1 = new Foo(1);
        Foo foo2 = new Foo(2);

        System.out.print(foo1.equals(foo2));
    }
}

class Foo {
    Integer code;

    Foo(Integer c) {
        code = c;
    }

    public boolean equals(Foo f) {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object f) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

When I run the code I get `false` 
but when I remove

```
public boolean equals(Foo f) {
        return false;
    }
```

and run the code I get `true`... 
Why is that and what is happening ?

Thanks

Comment: Hint: an object of Foo inherits from Object.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31019157/how-do-all-classes-inherit-from-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method Overloading.** Most specific method gets chosen at run time.

As per  [Language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.2) most specific method chooses at run time.

> If more than one member method is both accessible and applicable to a method invocation, it is necessary to choose one to provide the descriptor for the run-time method dispatch. The Java programming language uses the rule that the most specific method is chosen.

You are getting false because most specific method got choosen. That is the reason

```
 public boolean equals(Foo f) {
        return false;
    }
```

This method called and returning false. When you remove this method,

```
 public boolean equals(Object f) {
        return true;
    }
```

This gets called because every Foo is Object.

Answer (score 3):

This is `method overloading resolution`. There are two method candidates, one that takes an `Object` and the other takes `Foo`, when you pass a Foo, the `most specific` method (the one that takes Foo) will be called.

When you remove the method that takes Foo, you won't have an overload any longer and because `Foo` **is** an `Object` (as any class in Java) the method will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Because the compiler is going to invoke the **most-specific** method matching the parameters. When you have `equals(Foo)` that is more specific than `equals(Object)`. When you remove `equals(Foo)` the `equals(Object)` is the only method that is still valid. It is also worth noting that `Foo` has an implicit parent class, `java.lang.Object`.

Answer (score -1):

i think you don,t really understand object oriented programming, you should get a book on OOP to understand the consepts. check it-ebboks.com for some helpfull books

An objact is an instance of a class, take for instance a classroom of student offering the same subjects , if john doe is a memebr of that  class that is he offers the courses in that class he is an instance of that class

```
public boolean equals(Foo f) {
    return false;
}
```

is returning false no mattter what parameter you pass into it